# How to get onTap in Polygon in osmdroid?

Tags: maps, polygon, openstreetmap, android-maps, osmdroid

I have lot's of polygon drawn. Some of which overlaps. I want to be able to detect a tap inside the polygon and display a dialog saying it was clicked inside the polygon (this polygon should be detected on tap). This kind of property can be seen with **ItemizedIconOverlay** where we can detect all of the OverlayItem with the tap on the OverlayItem. How to implement this on polygon?

The way I draw and add Polygon is:

```
MyPolygon myNewPolygon = new MyPolygon(this);
myPolygon.setPoints(Polygon.pointsAsCircle(new GeoPoint(38.948714, -76.831918), 20000.0));
map.getOverlays().add(myPolygon);
myNewPolygon.setPoints(Polygon.pointsAsCircle(new GeoPoint(38.851777, -77.037878), 20000.0));
map.getOverlays().add(myNewPolygon);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various answers, depending on what you want to achieve exactly.

Simple case: if you just want to have a bubble opening, then just set an InfoWindow to your Polygon, as described in the tutorial.

If you want anything else: for Polygons, there is no Listener available, as there are for Markers and Polylines (an enhancement to request, maybe?).

So what you can do is sub-class Polygon - as you did with your MyPolygon. Then override onTap method - or most likely onSingleTapConfirmed - and implement the behaviour you need.

Looking at [Polygon.onSingleTapConfirmed](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/overlays/Polygon.java) source may help (hit test for instance).

Comment: I did it that way but what happens is with every Tap, all of the  Polygon.onSingleTapConfirmed() method of every polygon is called. For instance I have 20 polygons and even if I click in one of them or just simply anywhere on the map, regardless calls the  Polygon.onSingleTapConfirmed() method 20 times.

Comment: And,because of the overlapping polygons, the polygon that is below, it's InfoWindow won't be clicked, which is why I need to know how many polygon's are overlayed on that particular click location

Comment: Answer to 1) Yes. This is why in onSingleTapConfirmed you MUST perform a "hit test", using Polygon.contains method. If the tap is on the polygon, then you should return true: this is "consuming the event", and the method will not be called on any other overlay "under" this one. Answer to 2) Yes. Overlays are checked in descending order. So a Polygon covered by other Polygons will not be clickable. Quite usual. Do you expect another behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm using it:

```
class CustomTapPolygon extends Polygon {

    private CustomObject tag;

    public CustomObject getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(CustomObject tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && contains(e)) {
             // YOUR CODE HERE
             return true;
        }
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e, mapView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried osmbonuspack yet? I know for certain that there's an onclick listener for polygons in it.

Comment: I haven't been able to trace the Onclick listener for polygons. The best I could do was extend MapEventsOverlay and on it's OnSingleTapUp use the Polygon's contains(Event e) method to pass the Tap method to detect the click on polygon. Could you please guide me with the onclick listener for polygons. Thanks

Comment: And I'm using osmbonuspack_v5.3