# How to override the KML onTouchEvent?

Tags: osmdroid

I want to add my logic that will execute when the user has clicked a feature on the map.

I noticed that when I click on a feature on the `FolderOverlay`, it opens a  tooltip on the map that says "name" and "Description" next to the polygon  I click. Perfect.

I read the `onTouchEvent` in the `FolderOverlay.java`, but cannot understand how does that function find the currently pressed Polygon?

Here is the function:

```
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView){
    if (isEnabled())
        return mOverlayManager.onTouchEvent(e, mapView);
    else 
        return false;
}
```

In short, how do I register my logic to the event "user has clicked a feature on the map"

Thanks

Comment: FolderOverlay is just container for other overlays so it just delegates the touch event to contained children. I am not sure how KML is implemented in the library but it will probably generate polygons / polylines encapsulated in folderoverlay. Those are responsible for tap handling and deciding if tap ocured in their area.  For example here is source [code for polygon](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/0e63c3dd07fc9e43ba3c8b1ffb6c873d48515d2b/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Polygon.java#L242)

Comment: For polygons etc. this answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977376/how-to-get-ontap-in-polygon-in-osmdroid but it may be difficult to use in your scenario.

Comment: @JosefAdamcik Thanks for the tip. You are right, it is difficult to use in my example because the polygons are instantiated from the KML document, not me directly. But I'll try :). If you think of something else, let me know please.